# What does "Monpiece" mean?

Tags: monster-monpiece

What does "Monpiece" mean?

Presumably. "Mon-" means Monster, like in *Digimon* and *Pokemon*, but why "-piece"? Is it just a contraction of "game piece"?

But if "Mon-" does mean "Monster", then it's a bit redundant, given that the full name is "Monster Monpiece".

Comment: Pretty borderline, but I feel that this kinda falls under developer intent